# Importing a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv, client-server, import-csv

I am creating a marketplace that users can import products into. I need to be able to import the CSV file through a network I/O so with a client-server functionality.

Currently when I import the CSV filepath the GUI (program) freezes and I believe it is trying to read something that is not there or something along those lines.

Client:

```
public void importFromCSV(String path) {
    
    try {
        writer.write(path);
        writer.flush();
        int bytes = 0;
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        
        // send file size
        dos.writeLong(file.length());
        // break file into chunks
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        while ((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            dos.flush();
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public static void importCSV(Store store) {
    try {
        int bytes = 0;
        System.out.println("about to read path");
        String path = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("read path");
        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);

        long size = dis.readLong();     // read file size
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytes = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            size -= bytes;      // read upto file size
        }
        fos.close();

        store.setProducts(CSVFileWork.CSVToProducts(path));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(store.getProducts().size());
}
```

Comment: `the GUI (program) freezes` This is almost always from trying to executing long running code on the GUI event thread.  Please show us how `importFromCSV` is called in relation to the GUI code.  To run a task as a background task, look at [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Read this: [The Java™ Tutorials - Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)